# Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to switch among persistently running UI activities leads to "no window focus" error

Tags: android, window, focus

My objective is to keep two UI activities alive and to switch back and forth between them at will without having to kill/restart either of them.  But there is a serious side effect of using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** to do this: a loss of window focus when I resume a previous activity (that is currently running in the background).

I proved this issue by spending 5 minutes creating a simple application with two "Hello World" activities.

1. The app starts with Activity A, which simply shows a button (nothing else) called "Launch B".
2. Press this button -- this executes `startActivity(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, ActivityB.class).`
3. Activity B becomes active, which shows simply shows a button called "Launch A".
4. Press this button -- this executes `startActivity(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, ActivityA.class).`
5. Activity A's `onResume()` is called as expected and everything looks fine (I can see Activity A content again).
6. Press the device's Back key and this set of errors will occur 100% of the time:

> E/ActivityManager(  513): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting
>   because no window has focus but there is a focused application that
>   may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
>
> I/WindowState(  513): WIN DEATH: Window{5294687c u0
>   com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
>
> W/ViewRootImpl( 8066): **Dropping event due to no window focus**:
>   KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0,
>   metaState=0, flags=0xc8, repeatCount=1, eventTime=14965546,
>   downTime=14965045, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }

(The practical result of the window death is essentially a "crash" from the user's point of view -- Android throws the user out of the app back to the Home screen, though technically the application remains running in the background.)

I debugged this and found that the reason Activity A is visible but doesn't have focus is because activity A's **onWindowFocusChanged() is NOT called** like it normally does (even though onResume() is called).  **This has something to do with the fact with Activity B is still active in the background** (even though clearly B has lost focus -- onWindowFocusChanged(false) was called for B, as well as onStop()).  **I know this because after step 4 above if I immediately call finish() on Activity B, Activity A's onWindowFocusChanged(true) WILL be called and everything is normal.**  The fact that Activity B is still active but not focused somehow interferes with Activity A regaining focus like it should.  Is this an Android bug or am I missing something?

Note that if Activity A had multiple views in it and I were to touch one of those views after step 6 above, I would get the same "Dropping event due to no window focus" error, though not 100% of the time for some reason.

Comment: It's a bug introduced in Lollipop, see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91534

Comment: OK, actually the bug was introduced in 4.4.2: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63570

Comment: Well-stated question with good ideas about the cause!  Btw, this is also being tracked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804474 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418683

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to this issue.  In my project, my "Activity A" is always active, so when I'm switching to A from my "Activity B", I always then kill B immediately.  This is my only workaround.  I would have preferred to keep B open, instead of having to restart it again later, but I see no other way to prevent this crash.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround provided in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63570#c15 worked pretty well for me to resolve the issue of Activity not getting window focus:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if ((intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) > 0) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && !isTaskRoot()) {
            ActivityManager tasksManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            tasksManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_NO_USER_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

This will also need the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

I actually run into this issue in `Espresso` test getting such error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Otherwise, something is seriously wrong.`