# Android-L issue: onBackpressed when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to launch previous activity & freezes app for sometime

Tags: android

My application has a strange behaviour

I proved this issue by following steps on Android L O.S. devices like Nexus 7 or Moto G.

1. The app starts with Activity A, which simply shows a button called "Launch B".
2. Press this button -- this executes **startActivity(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, ActivityB.class)**.
3. Activity B becomes active, which do some UI and backhand loading operation on UI thread.
4. After pressing back from Activity B, OnBackPressed Of Activity B, this executes startActivity(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, ActivityA.class).
5. Activity A's onResume() is called as expected and everything looks fine (I can see Activity A content again).
6. Press the device's Back key and App freezes for around 10 seconds or more and comes out of application. Without calling onPause(), onDestroy().
   (So it may be anr with certain logs)
7. Sometime or may be repeating same above step for 4-5 times it also unfortunately force close googlequicksearchbox

After looking at system logs:
found some important logs:

```
E/ActivityManager(  958): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```

Important Logs: Have a look

```
D/SFPerfTracer(  278):        layers: (2:12) (FocusedStackFrame (0xb8fa6b48): 0:637)* (DimLayer (0xb8fa95c0): 0:14)* (DimLayer (0xb8fe63b0): 0:510)* (DimLayer (0xb8fb7228): 0:213)* (StatusBar (0xb8fd10c0): 0:5421)* (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xb8fd6a28): 0:454)* (NavigationBar (0xb8fbaa18): 8:744) (com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity (0xb8fbbca8): 0:86)- (com.abc.myapp/com.mypackage.abc.MainActivity (0xb8fd3560): 0:25)- (thumbnail anim (0xb8ff72b0): 0:12)- (com.abc.myapp/com.mypackage.abc_etv.EtvLaunchActivity (0xb8ffb570): 14:34) 

I/LaunchCheckinHandler(  958): Displayed com.abc.myapp/com.mypackage.abc.MainActivity,wp,wa,286

I/WindowManager(  958): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{23d5f06c token=Token{299ea51f ActivityRecord{2f0940be u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL t4}}}.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.

I/WindowManager(  958): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{23d5f06c token=Token{299ea51f ActivityRecord{2f0940be u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL t4}}}.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.

E/ActivityManager(  958): ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL)

E/ActivityManager(  958): PID: 655

E/ActivityManager(  958): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```

Comment: btw, this is same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418683 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111320/