# ANR in com.android.launcher after tapping back

Tags: android

When I install my app on certain devices (seems to be 4.4.4 and later) I sometimes see the following ANR in com.android.launcher after the following steps:

1. From Activity A, launch Activity B
2. In Activity B, press system back key and in the onBackPressed() method of Activity B relaunch Activity A (code is below).
3. System back key remains in pressed state for 5 seconds, the screen turns black, my app gets closed and Launcher comes up. Investigating the logs shows an ANR in the Launcher process.

> ANR in com.android.launcher
>   (com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher) Reason: Input
>   dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there
>   is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it
>   finishes starting up.)

Notice that the ANR is occurring in com.android.launcher (not in my app).

Btw, I am NOT doing an expensive operation in my onBackPressed/onPause/onStop methods.

The logs also show that onBackPressed() is not being invoked when the ANR occurs - very odd behavior as you can see here:

```
## User starts Activity A from Android Launcher
D/Activity A: onResume()
D/Activity A: onClick(): start Activity B
D/Activity A: onPause()
D/Activity B: onResume()

## User taps system back key (and onBackPressed() launches Activity A)
D/Activity B: onBackPressed(): start Activity A
D/Activity B: onPause()
D/Activity A: onResume()
D/Activity A: onClick(): start Activity B
D/Activity A: onPause()
D/Activity B: onResume()

## User taps system back key (but onBackPressed() is not invoked. Instead an ANR occurs)
I/InputDispatcher(  557): ANR in com.android.launcher
D/Activity B: onPause()
```

Here is my onBackPressed() method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intentStartRoot = new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName(this, ActivityHome.class));
    intentStartRoot.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intentStartRoot);
}
```

Comment: post your onbackpress code

Comment: I added the onBackPressed() code. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably a bug in the Android Framework. I tested on about 12 devices today and noticed that this bug occurs reliably on Nexus-type devices running these versions of Android:

- 4.4.4
- 5.0.1
- 5.0.2

Interestingly, Samsung devices running the same versions of Android do not exhibit the problem. Android 5.1 and later seems to be better in that I see no more ANRs in com.android.launcher; however I am now seeing ANRs in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.

I worked around this problem after noticing that my Activity was overriding onBackPressed() without invoking super.onBackPressed().
After I added super.onBackPressed(), the ANRs went away. But this is not a full workaround because calling super.onBackPressed() finished my Activity, which I do not want.

I hope this helps someone.

See: [Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to switch among persistently running UI activities leads to "no window focus" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111320)

See: [Android-L issue: onBackpressed when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to launch previous activity & freezes app for sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804474)

Also, I found a bug entry on Google's site that seems related:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91534

Comment: that is not true, if you override onbackpressed and do nothing, nothing will be done and hence no anr,

Comment: That would normally true but not in my case because my onBackPressed() method was starting Activity A. I have edited my original question to include this information. Thanks for your suggestion that I include the source code.

Comment: Similar experience. I have 2 activities that i can switch back and forth using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. The weirdest thing is: the bug happen only if I switch from A->B->A.. It doesn't happen on A->B, or A->B->A->B, or even A->B->A->B->A, or any other combination.. I might as well put this problem on the Known Issues part of my software's readme. And true, mostly happen on nexusian 4.x to 5.x (emulators).. tried 6.x emulator and it's ok. tried on my own non nexus phone, and it works fine also.